# Bit manipulation issues with signed and unsigned ints, XNOR

Tags: c++, cuda

I am implementing a parallel radix sort, I am trying to do a scan on the bit values at a specific bit index to compute offset addresses for radix. I am trying to do the scan in two passes, on for bit values of '0' and one for bit values of '1'.

I am trying to create a flag of whether I want to work with a specific bit value or not. I pass a boolean flag into my kernel that states whether I want to work with bits that are '0' or '1', the flag is called `doOnes`. If the flag is true, and the bit value is 1, then I want to set another flag `useBit` to true so I know to take it into account in my kernel. If the flag is true, and the bit value is 0, then I want the `useBit` flag to be false.

I can confirm that I am getting the proper bit value. My issue is computing `useVal` below.

```
// This simulates the flag passed to the kernel
bool doOnes = false;

// This simulates the unsigned int bit value that I get within my kernel
unsigned int bitVal1 = 1;
unsigned int bitVal0 = 0;
printf("> BitVal1: %u  BitVal0: %u \n", bitVal1, bitVal0);

// Here is how I determine if I want to use the data at the bits index or not
int useVal1 = ~(bitVal1 ^ doOnes); // XNOR = ~(val1 ^ val2)
int useVal0 = ~(bitVal0 ^ doOnes);
printf("> BitVal1X: %i  BitVal0X: %i \n", useVal1 , useVal0);
```

Here is the output produced

```
> BitVal1: 1  BitVal0: 0 
> BitVal1X: -2  BitVal0X: -1
```

How can I properly combine the flag `doOnes` and the bit value to determine if I want to use it?

EDIT:

Here is what I want

```
doOnes  |  bitVal | useBit = XNOR(doOnes, bitVal)
------------------------------
true    |    0    |  false  
true    |    1    |  true
false   |    0    |  true
false   |    1    |  false
```

Comment: Sorry.. I had changed the variable names for the question to make it easier to explain. Made an edit above, its correct now.

Comment: For `BitVal1X` I expect '0' or false, and for `BitVal0X` I expect '1' or true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unary operator `~` reverses all bits, you want the unary operator `!` which reverse the boolean value.

```
!(bitVal1 ^ doOnes)
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Rb8AEE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int useVal1 = (~(bitVal1 ^ (doOnes?1:0)))&1; // XNOR = ~(val1 ^ val2)
int useVal0 = (~(bitVal0 ^ (doOnes?1:0)))&1;
```

Regards

Comment: This still produces the same output as above.

Comment: I updated the answer. The issue was that the operation was done on all the 32 bits of the int.